# Walking a Drive

Tags: python, os.walk

At the moment, I am using `os.walk` to simply iterate all the files of the `C:` drive and it takes a great deal of time as expected when running as a single thread. How can I divide this file search amongst several threads so as to quickly perform this traverse of the file system?

Comment: By the way, I know Python threads are not really concurrent. They are actually mathematically offset successively by milliseconds. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Downvoter? Man, people are so quick to click.

Comment: Threading is not the solution here, since all the threads will still have to hit the hard drive in order to walk the filesystem. If anything, it can make things worse because the disk heads may have to jump from one location on the drive to another to accommodate the work of all the threads. This is nearly akin to expecting a baby in one month by impregnating nine women.

Comment: you could use `os.listdir` to get subdirectories of the drive, then pass one each to sub processes that can run concurrently to speed it up somewhat, but the improvement will depend on how many CPU cores you have available

Comment: @JamesKent Exactly, I have heard about processes, not really sure how they differ from threads though.

Comment: a thread is run within the context of the original python interpreter, but multiprocessing invokes a new process to run another python interpreter for each new task, thereby getting past pythons GIL the limits it to performing only one task at a time. but if you read the question linked to by João Gonçalves you'll see that `os.walk` is an IO bound task. so splitting it in this way would only be beneficial across multiple drives.